# Unreal Engine: How to edit the M_Athena_Terrain_IceBiome.M_Athena_Terrain_IceBiome material?

Tags: materials, unreal-5

I'm using the snow landscape as described here:

https://www.reddit.com/r/FortniteCreative/comments/12100h0/terrain_materials_uefn/

This is the full path to the material:

/Script/Engine.Material'/Game/Athena/Environments/Landscape/Creative/M_Athena_Terrain_IceBiome.M_Athena_Terrain_IceBiome'

However, I cannot find anywhere this M_Athena_Terrain_IceBiome.M_Athena_Terrain_IceBiom in content browser or file explorer. Double clicking on that material doesn't open anything. So, it seems that I cannot edit that material, and I can't even find/locate it.

If I can create a new material that's based on that Athena icebiome, that'd work too, but it seems like I can only create materials from scratch.

The reason I'm trying to edit this material is that I need to connect a landscape visibility mask to its Opacity Mask so I can use the Visibility tool to create a hole inside that snowy mountain/terrain.

I'm using Unreal Engine for Fortnite (UEFN), but I think it's pretty close to the full UE5.